# If URL matches this, insert script after opening body tag

Tags: javascript

I have a pixel script I want to insert only on a  certain page. Because of our awful CMS, I can't add it to the page itself, but I can add it to the master template ASP (I think it's ASP) file. I figured it would be easiest to do this in Javascript.

Right now I have this in the head, but I don't think printing the pixel script in the head will work:

```
<script>
if (location.href.indexOf("http://site.com/page1") !== -1) {
document.write('<script src="yadayada" type="text/javascript"></script>');
}
</script>
```

Comment: why not do this server side as you're parsing the page?

Comment: I don't know ASP, which is a weak excuse, I know.

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
if (location.href.indexOf("http://site.com/page1") !== -1) {
     var script = document.createElement("script");
     script.src="yadayada.js";
     script.type="text/javascript";
     script.onload=function(){
     // callback after script loading is complete
     // your script dependent code goes here
 }
document.body.appendChild(script)
}
</script>
```

This is how it can be done

Comment: So if I just want to add the yadayada.js file to the body of the document and don't have dependent code, I don't need to add anything to the lines you commented out?

Comment: I'm getting an error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'appendChild' of null` on the last line of the script

Comment: that because your script resides in head. while rendering the browser does not have the body to append a child to it. write this code inside the body and it will work

Comment: I placed it right after the opening body tag, but when I look at the source I only see the script with the If statement.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously, it would be better to do this on backend, but if you really can not, here is what is wrong with your code:

The `</script>` part of the string you are trying to append to the document is actually closing your script tag in the head.

This is a common approach to avoid this problem:

```
document.write('<script src="yadayada" type="text/javascript"></' + 'script>');
```

Other solution would be to create the script element using `document.createElement`:

```
var script   = document.createElement("script");
script.type  = "text/javascript";
script.src  = "example.com/somescript.js"; 
document.body.appendChild(script);
```